# Solving a PDE geometrically

Tags: geometry, linear-pde

Suppose I want to solve a 1st order linear PDE $$xu_x-yu_y=0,\qquad u(x,0)=f(x)$$
The solution obtained from Lagrange's equation is $u(x,y)=f(y/x)$. Here the characteristics look like rectangular hyperbola. How do I look at this pde from the geometric viewpoint so that I can get an intuitive picture of the solution by inspection without actually solving the pde ?

Comment: The best 'geometrical' viewpoint I've seen given is in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467264/solution-of-the-pde-which-has-cauchy-data) by @Jean Marie. In your case, you have $(dx,dy,du) \propto (y,x,u) \times (0,0,1)$. Can you see how $(0,0,1)$ gives one characteristic and $(y,x,u)$ gives the characteristic for the hyperbola?

Comment: @Mattos, thanks for the link. I will go through it.